# Unable to display the image in React inspite it is imported in the folder

Tags: reactjs

I have pasted the image in `assets` folder and after importing the image in `header` folder it is displaying the error as

**src/components/header/header.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../assets/crown.svg' in 'C:\Users\Harshit\Desktop\e-commerce\src\components\header'
console. @ index.js:1**

So,What should I do??

````
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {ReactComponent as Logo }from '../../assets/crown.svg';
import './header.scss';

const Header=()=>
(
    <div className='header'>
        <Link className='logo-container' to="/">
            <Logo className='logo'/>


        </Link>
        <div className='options'>
            <Link className='option' to='/shop'>
                SHOP
            </Link>

            <Link className='option' to='/shop'>
                CONTACT
            </Link>

        </div>

    </div>
)

export default Header;```
````

Comment: check if the path you are importing from has image in it actually?

Comment: Where is your assets directory located relative to "e-commerce"?

Comment: my assets directory is inside the src folder...